# simple attempt to sort inline returns None, don't know why

Tags: python, python-2.7

To make a sorted list of values that appear in set a, This works:

```
a = [1,1,7,3,2,9,2]
b = list(set(a))
b.sort()
print b
```

but putting the two lines together, it returns None:

```
a = [1,1,7,3,2,9,2]
b = list(set(a)).sort()
print b
```

Even though these are true:

```
 type(list(set(a))) is list
 len(list(set(a)))  > 0
```

My question is, why doesn't the second method just return a sorted list - why do I have to put them on separate lines (as in the first method)?

Comment: for beginners like me, reminders that the question is also sometimes the answer (question: "...returns None"; answer: "...returns None") though it is obvious to those more experienced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sort` is an in place method, meaning it does not return a value. It simply performs a method of the given object, almost like a `void` method from other languages. If you'd like a single line, try:

```
b = sorted(list(set(a)))
```

Comment: Great! Now I understand both better, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`sort()` doesn't return a value, it just modifies the original object you pass in.

Comment: an 'oic' moment. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`sort()` sorts the list but doesn't return any result. You just end up with a nice sorted list. So you should do this:

```
b = list(set(a))
b.sort()
print(b)
```